# How to send a get request generated by Javascript in web scraping?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping

The website I test is powered with Ajax and when a control is clicked it sends the following request and loads dynamic data in the browser (not visible in the page source),

```
GET /_ajax/PDP/NearbyProperties/json/?tplname=small&bounds=40.394347,-74.108978,40.395981,-74.105502&lat=40.395164&lon=-74.10724&block_pid=1080560259&fips_id=34025
```

I got this using Firebug extension. How can this be sent as request from Python? Please help me with Python equivalent for the above request.

Am currently using Python 2.7 and selenium.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: will be grateful if you could help me with an example for my scenario. is this sent as HTTP request?

Comment: Check out Requests package, you need to make a request with parameters. You can find instruction's here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers